# getting onclient with AutoPostBack set to True in telerik radcalander

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, telerik

I have a telerik radcalandar control, it currently makes a post back which is fine but I want it to have a client function call too for getting onclientclick on selection changed.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with the below code snippet but not able to reproduce this issue.

**JS**

```
<telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock1" runat="server">
<script>
    function DateSelected(sender, args) {
        alert(args.get_renderDay()._date);
    }
</script>
```

**ASPX**

```
<telerik:RadCalendar ID="RadCalendar1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectionChanged="RadCalendar1_SelectionChanged">
        <ClientEvents OnDateSelected="DateSelected" />
    </telerik:RadCalendar>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

**ASPX.CS**

```
protected void RadCalendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.Calendar.SelectedDatesEventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = e.SelectedDates[e.SelectedDates.Count - 1].Date.ToString();
}
```